# Form Validation laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Alright , I made a form with a validation , okay , when I want to connect the validation in laravel I use this way

this is pages controller

```
 public function getContact(){

        self::$data['title'] = 'Contact us';
        return view('content.contact',self::$data);
    }

    public function postContact(test $request){       

    }


}
```

this is the routes :

```
Route::get('contact','PagesController@getContact');
Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@postContact');
```

and this is the form

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" href="{{asset('js/class.FormValidation.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="{{asset('js/landin_validation.js')}}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset ('js/style.css')}}"/>
  </head>
  <body>

          <form action="" method="post" class="landing-form">    
              {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <label>Fill your details here - </label><br/><br/>
            <input placeholder="Full name:" type="text" name="name" class="field-name" />
            <input placeholder="Email:" type="text" name="email" class="field-email" />
            <input placeholder="Phone Number:" type="text" name="phone" class="field-phone" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
```

Okay so , I tried a lot to connect the validation with the form , but since it's laravel so I know the requests way but I tried a lot to connect it with this validation but doesnt work ,

this is landin_validation.js

```
var formValidate = new FormValidation();

$(document).ready(function () {

  $('form.landing-form').submit(function () {

    // Collect client info from fields
    var name = $.trim( $('input[type="text"].field-name').val() );
    var email = $.trim( $('input[type="text"].field-email').val() );
    var phone = $.trim( $('input[type="text"].field-phone').val() );

    // Reset input fields error class
    $('input[type="text"]').removeClass('error');

    // Form validation
    if (!formValidate.testName(name) ) {
      $('input[type="text"].field-name').addClass('error');
      $('input[type="text"].field-name').val('');
      $('input[type="text"].field-name').attr('placeholder', '* Valid full name is required!');
    } else if ( !formValidate.testEmail(email) ) {
      $('input[type="text"].field-email').addClass('error');
      $('input[type="text"].field-email').val('');
      $('input[type="text"].field-email').attr('placeholder', '* Valid email is required!');
    } else if ( !formValidate.testPhone(phone) ) {
      $('input[type="text"].field-phone').addClass('error');
      $('input[type="text"].field-phone').val('');
      $('input[type="text"].field-phone').attr('placeholder', '* Valid phone is required!');
    } else {

      // Open ajax call to save client details + send mail to customer
      $.ajax({
        url: "form_handler.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        async: "false",
        data: {name: name, email: email, phone: phone},
        beforeSend: function () {
          var messege = '<img src="ajax-loader.gif" border="0">';
          messege += '&nbsp;&nbsp;Sending... ';
          $('form.landing-form label').html(messege);
        },
        success: function (response) {

          if (response == true) {

            setTimeout(function(){

              $('div.form-wrapper').html('<label>Your details has been send!</label>');

            }, 2000);

          } else {

            $('div.form-wrapper').html('<label>Something went wrong, please try again later...</label>');

          }
        }
      });
    }

    // Stop form submission
    return false;

  });
});
```

And this is FormValidation.js

```
function FormValidation(){

  this.nameReg = [
    /^([a-zA-Z\s]+){2,255}$/
  ];

  this.emailReg = [
    /^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/
  ];

  this.phoneReg = [
    /^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i,
    /^[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}$/i,
    /^\([0-9]{3}\)-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i,
    /^[0-9]{9,10}$/i
  ];

  this.testName = function( nameInput ){

    return this.inputCheck(this.nameReg, nameInput);

  };

  this.testEmail = function( emailInput ){

    return this.inputCheck(this.emailReg, emailInput);

  };

  this.testPhone = function( phoneInput ){

    return this.inputCheck(this.phoneReg, phoneInput);

  };

  this.inputCheck = function( regArray, inputData ){

    var valid = false;

    $.each( regArray, function( key, val ){

      if( val.test( inputData ) ){

        valid = true;

      }

    });

    return valid;

  };

}
```

I just want to know the way to connect the form with this validation.

Comment: why not use jquery validation . Use both server and client side validation

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not good idea to validate form data with js.Аccording to me you should validate from the server-side.If you want to have good user experience you can use this javascript lib - **http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/**